# как получить элемент с помощью css-селектора (selenium)

Tags: css, google-chrome, selenium, css-selectors

Используя Selenium, хочу получить элемент "Моя лента" через сss-селектор (cм.скриншот) в Google Chrome.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую селектор, который выдает хром следующим образом:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

        def wait_and_get_element(driver, locator):
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, locator)))
            return element

        def test_search():
    //тут пропущен переход до вкладки 'Картинки'
           element = wait_and_get_element(driver, 'body > div.serp-navigation.z-index-group.z-index-group_level_8 > div > div > div.navigation__'
                                'item.navigation__item_service_yes.navigation__item_name_images > div > a > span')
```

Последняя строка возвращает ошибку:

```
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

То есть элемент не был найден, а значит я, вероятно, неправильно указываю селектор. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема?